# How to create an SFrame compatible with TuriCreate for object detection task

Tags: object-detection, sframe, createml

I am trying to create an `SFrame` containing images and bounding boxes' coordinates, in order to perform object detection using `TuriCreate`.
I have created my own dataset by [IBM Cloud Annotations](https://cloud.annotations.ai/login), exported as `CreateML` format. When I  run:

`usage_data = tc.SFrame.read_json("annotations.json")`

I get:

*[{'label': 'xyz'... | 8be1172e-44bb-4084-917f-db....*

Which is not the format requested. It is confirmed running the code below:

```
data = tc.SFrame.read_json("annotations.json")

train_data, test_data = data.random_split(0.75)

model = tc.object_detector.create(train_data)

predictions = model.predict(test_data)
```

`I get:

```
ToolkitError: No "feature" column specified and no column with expected type "image" is found. "datasets" consists of columns with types: list, str.
```

I would like to know:

1. Is it correct export data in `CreateML` format?
2. Can I use `SFrame.read_json()` for reading this kind of data?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an SFrame from your images folder and then join it to your annotations SFrame like:

```
imagesSFrame = turicreate.image_analysis.load_images('imagesFolder/')
combinedSFrame = images.join(annotationsSFrame)
```

Just make sure that your annotations each have a path that exactly matches the path in your imagesSFrame. Below is my csv format:

```
path, annotation,
imagesFolder/image1.png,[{'label': 'dog', 'coordinates': {'height': 118, 'width': 240, 'x': 155, 'y': 129}}]
```

`print(imagesSFrame)` will allow you to inspect what the path is inside your imagesSFrame